# How to fetch the details of latest snapshot in a text file in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, amazon-ec2

I have a script in batch which contains the code

```
:: Create a file with all latest snapshots
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%a in (' ec2-describe-snapshots ^|find "SNAPSHOT" ^|sort /+64') do set "var=%%a" 
set "latestdate=%var:~0,10%" 
call ec2-describe-snapshots |find "SNAPSHOT"|sort /+64 |find "%latestdate%">"%EC2_HOME%\Working\SnapshotsLatest_%date-today%.txt"
```

I need to convert the batch script to linux shell script . how can i do that. i need to fetch the information of all the latest snapshots created on a latest date. like on 2013-12-10 ( the date format )

Thanks

Comment: provide input data and output requirement

Comment: i have some snapshots made on amazon, i want to find the latest snapshots made on a date and then want to store them in a file. like date 2013-12-10 snapshots made on this date should be stored in file. Contents of snapshotslatest file should be `SNAPSHOT snap-c17f3 vol-f69a0 completed 2013-12-04T09:24:50+0000 100% 109030037‌​527 10 2013-12-04: Daily Backup for Sanjay_Test_Machine (VolID:vol-f66409a0 InstID:i-26048111) SNAPSHOT snap-c7d617f9 vol-3d335f6b completed 2013-12-04T09:24:54+0000 100% 1090‌​30037527 10 2013-12-04: Daily Backup for sacht_VPC (VolID:vol-3db InstID:i-ed6)'

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
LATESTDATE=`ec2-describe-snapshots | grep "SNAPSHOT" | awk '{print $5}' | sort | cut -d "T" -f 1 | tail -1`
ec2-describe-snapshots | grep "SNAPSHOT" | grep ${LATESTDATE} > ~/SnapshotLatest_`date`.txt
```